# Configuration change in loader

Tags: android

The one of the advantage of loaders over asynctask is that they can handle configuration change ie rotation.But I am not able to understand how they do this and what exactly this means.Can anyone give a suitable example for this?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you use a `CursorLoader` to retrieve data from a `ContentProvider`.

Then, suppose the user rotates the screen from portrait to landscape. Your portrait activity will be destroyed, and a new instance of your activity will be created so that you can display your landscape UI.

The `CursorLoader` will *not* re-retrieve the data from the `ContentProvider`. Rather, your new activity instance will be handed back the same `Cursor` that had been delivered to your original activity instance.

`Activity` (for API Level 11+) and `FragmentActivity` (for API Level 10 and below) both will retain the `CursorLoader` and its `Cursor` across the configuration change. You can use a retained fragment (i.e., a fragment on which you call `setRetainInstance(true)`) to also retain arbitrary objects across configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders are more useful than asyntask in many cases of screen orientation and all.Coding is easy in loaders

You can see a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078119/what-is-the-advantage-of-loaders-over-asynctask-in-android)