# Update UI from an AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android-asynctask, android, asynctaskloader

I've converted my `AsyncTask` to an `AsyncTaskLoader` (mostly to deal with configuration changes).  I have a `TextView` I am using as a progress status and was using `onProgressUpdate` in the `AsyncTask` to update it.  It doesn't look like `AsyncTaskLoader` has an equivalent, so during `loadInBackground` (in the `AsyncTaskLoader`) I'm using this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Updating...");
    }
});
```

I am using this in a `Fragment`, which is why I'm using `getActivity()`.  This work pretty well, except when a configuration change happens, like changing the screen orientation.  My `AsyncTaskLoader` keeps running (which is why I'm using an `AsyncTaskLoader`), but the `runOnUiThread` seems to get skipped.

Not sure why it's being skipped or if this is the best way to update the UI from an  `AsyncTaskLoader`.

UPDATE:

I ended up reverting back to an `AsyncTask` as it seems better suited for UI updates.  Wish they could merge what works with an `AsyncTask` with an `AsyncTaskLoader`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually possible. You essentially need to subclass the `AsyncTaskloader` and implement a `publishMessage()` method, which will use a `Handler` to deliver the progress message to any class that implements the `ProgressListener` (or whatever you want to call it) interface.

Download this for an example: http://www.2shared.com/file/VW68yhZ1/SampleTaskProgressDialogFragme.html (message me if it goes offline) - this was based of http://habrahabr.ru/post/131560/

Comment: I think this is a very clever hack. I never thought about it. I was looking for the way to send my progress updates using Loaders. I am gonna give it a try and let you know. I think your solution should work!!

Comment: The link seems to have gone bad. [Here](https://yadi.sk/d/qovznXrpUbbum)'s a working one (I think it's the same).

Answer (score 4):

Emm... you shouldn't be doing this.

because how an anonymous class access parent class Method or Field is by storing an invisible reference to the parent class.

for example you have a `Activity`:

```
public class MyActivity
    extends Activity
{
    public void someFunction() { /* do some work over here */ }

    public void someOtherFunction() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true)
                    someFunction();
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start(); // use it, for example here just make a thread to run it.
    }
}
```

the compiler will actually generate something like this:

```
private static class AnonymousRunnable {
    private MyActivity parent;
    public AnonymousRunnable(MyActivity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            parent.someFunction();
    }
}
```

So, when your parent `Activity` destroys (due to configuration change, for example), and your anonymous class still exists, the whole activity cannot be gc-ed. (because someone still hold a reference.)

**THAT BECOMES A MEMORY LEAK AND MAKE YOUR APP GO LIMBO!!!**

If it was me, I would implement the "onProgressUpdate()" for loaders like this:

```
public class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Something> {
    private Observable mObservable = new Observable();
    synchronized void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        mObservable.addObserver(observer);
    }
    synchronized void deleteObserver(Observer observer) {
        mObservable.deleteObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInBackground(CancellationSignal signal)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < 100;++i)
            mObservable.notifyObservers(new Integer(i));
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity` class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Observer mObserver = new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
            final Integer progress = (Integer) data;
            mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                mTextView.setText(data.toString()); // update your progress....
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MyLoader loader = (MyLoader) getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        loader.addObserver(mObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        MyLoader loader = (MyLoader) getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
        if (loader != null)
            loader.deleteObserver(mObserver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

remember to `deleteObserver()` during `onDestroy()` is important, this way the loader don't hold a reference to your activity forever. (the loader will probably be held alive during your `Application` lifecycle...)

Comment: It seems you are missing a setChanged() on the Observable, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, but from what I can tell, `AsyncTaskLoader` isn't the best to use if you need to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In the class in which you implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallback` (presumably your Activity), there is an `onLoadFinished()` method which you must override. This is what is returned when the `AsyncTaskLoader` has finished loading.

Comment: I may be mistaken but isn't `onLoadFinished` called when the `AsyncTaskLoader` is done loading?  Not exactly sure how that addresses my issue, but I'm new to `AsyncTaskLoaders` so I may be missing something.  Is `onLoadFinished` the equivalent to `onProgressUpdate` in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: It's the equivalent of `onPostExecute`

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.  I need the equivalent of `onProgressUpdate`, so I can show a status as the background process is running.  I don't think `AsyncTaskLoader` has one.

Answer (score 0):

**The best method is to use LiveData, 100% Working**

Step 1: Add lifecycle dependency or use androidx artifacts as yes during project creation

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0"
```

Step 2: Create the loader class as follow, in loader create in public method to set the livedata that can be observed from activity or fragment. see the **setLiveCount** method in my loader class.

```
package com.androidcodeshop.asynctaskloaderdemo;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<String>> {

private MutableLiveData<Integer> countLive = new MutableLiveData<>();


synchronized public void setLiveCount(MutableLiveData<Integer> observer) {
    countLive = (observer);
}


public ContactLoader(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ArrayList<String> loadInBackground() {
    return loadNamesFromDB();
}

private ArrayList<String> loadNamesFromDB() {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            names.add("Name" + i);
            countLive.postValue(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return names;
}


@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    super.onStartLoading();
    forceLoad(); // forcing the loading operation everytime it starts loading
}
}
```

Step 3: Set the live data from activity and observe the change as follows

```
package com.androidcodeshop.asynctaskloaderdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList> {

private ContactAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> mNames;
private MutableLiveData<Integer> countLiveData;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, mNames);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    countLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    countLiveData.observe(this, new androidx.lifecycle.Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + integer);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + 
    integer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // initialize the loader in onCreate of activity
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    // it's deprecated the best way is to use viewmodel and livedata while loading data
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {

    ContactLoader loader = new ContactLoader(this);
    loader.setLiveCount(countLiveData);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList> load, ArrayList data) {
    mNames.clear();
    mNames.addAll(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader loader) {
    mNames.clear();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Hope this will help you :) happy coding