# Android SQLite get all data from cursor fast

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, cursor

I am dealing with a performance problem in one of my apps. Maybe one of you guys can help me out?!

I have a database with somewhat around 10k entries.
I query for elements using the default *query* method from the [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)-class.
The query itself is fast enough.

Once the query is complete I have to display the results on a Google Map.
For that I generate a result array from the cursor which holds the marker information.

The method I use looks somewhat like this:

```
    final ArrayList< MarkerElement > result = new ArrayList< MarkerElement >();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
        result.add( new MarkerElement(
                cursor.getString( COL_TITLE ),
                cursor.getString( COL_SNIPPET ),
                new LatLng(
                        cursor.getDouble( COL_LAT ),
                        cursor.getDouble( COL_LNG ) ),
                cursor.getString( COL_OTHER_USEFUL_DATA ) );
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Where *MarkerElement* is simply a class that holds the required values for a Marker on a Google Map.

The problem now is, that looping through all cursor elements takes by far to long.
Also I cannot think of a smart way to lazy load the results like in a ListView because I need to show all results simultaneously.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this process significantly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

I'm not so sure the query is really as fast as you think it is. Most likely the actual query is only executed with the cursor.moveToFirst() statement and not when calling query() or rawQuery() (or whatever other query method you're using).

Anyway the query should be fast enough to keep the user waiting only shortly. If not then you might want to consider loading it in chunks using SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT START, COUNT (e.g. SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 0, 1000 to retrieve the first 1000 rows).

The query can't happen on the ui thread so you want to run it in an AsyncTaskLoader or better even a CursorLoader. A CursorLoader without ContentProvider is possible as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422343/534471.

Let's assume you need to run 10 queries for 1000 records each, then you would have 10 CursorLoaders that you could manage using a LoaderManager. LoaderManager manages the cursors (opens and closes them), retains the cursors across orientation changes and runs everything in a background task so no issues with blocking the ui thread. LoaderManager also re-queries the db should the content change (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5603959/534471).
When the LoaderManager notifies your fragment or your activity that a cursor has finished loading it will call onLoadFinished() (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html).

What slows down your code isn't just querying the database but also creating 10'000 MarkerElement and another 10'000 LatLng objects. I don't know your requirements but if you see any chance to work without these objects that would certainly speed up your code. Another desirable effect of eliminating the MarkerElements/LatLng is memory usage. For an app targeting phones 20'000 objects with 3 Strings and 2 Double is considerable.

Using CursorLoaders and LoaderManager would allow you to retrieve the values from the cursor and to populate your ui views directly without MarkerElements and LatLng. It would also allow you to load lazily. You can populate the views whenever onLoadFinished() is called for one of the CursorLoaders (onLoadFinished() is called on the ui thread unless the initLoader/restartLoader is called from a non-ui thread). If 1000 views is too much to populate at once, either break down the query into smaller pieces or add a mechanism to populate the views in chunks of 10s or 100s (for each cursor).

In case you need the information you currently store in MarkerElement e.g. when the user selects one of the markers, use setTag() on the view that displays the marker to store the primary key of the db record. Use the key to either retrieve the record from the db or better even from the already queried cursors (that will need some mapping mechanism but it's doable).

Summary:

- Split the query into several sub queries to retrieve smaller sets of data
- Use CursorLoaders and CursorManager to manage the different queries/cursors
- Don't create a MarkerElement and a LatLng for each row but populate the views directly from the returned cursors
- Possibly do the populate for each cursor in several steps to keep the ui responsive
- use the setTag() on the views to be able to retrieve the data behind the view